# Grouping List elements and map to new model using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of items that should be converted to another data structure using  Linq statements. I am able to group list, however, I cannot correctly create subelements.

Here is my result model (simplified):

```
public class MyModel {
    string Name {get; set;}
    List<MySubmodel> Submodels {get;set;}
}

public class MySubmodel {
    string Id {get;set;}
    string Title {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Here is source:

```
public class SourceModel
        string Id {get;set;}
        string Title {get;set;}
        ...
        string Name {get;set;} // this is property for grouping
    }


public List<SourceModel> src = getList();
```

`src` list elements of class `SourceModel` partly match `MySubmodel` and I have a mapper that maps `src` list elements to `MySubmodel`).

```
IEnumerable<MyModel> t = from p in src
                        group p by p.Name into sl
                        select new MyModel()
                        {
                            Name = sl.Key,
                            // and I am not able to create MoelSublists object
                            ModelSublists = new List<MySubmodels>() 
                        };
```

Comment: `ModelSublists` is of type `List<SourceModel>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to simply project the `IGrouping<string,MyModel>` object recieved after grouping. Try this:-

```
IEnumerable<MyModel> t = from p in src
                        group p by p.Name into sl
                        select new MyModel()
                        {
                            Name = sl.Key,
                            ModelSublists = sl.Select(x => new MySubmodel 
                                             {
                                                Id = x.Id,
                                                Title = x.Id         
                                             }).ToList()
                        };
```